# Im passing a vector to a function as a double but visual studio is calling it an unsigned int

Tags: c++, function, vector

I'm very new to programming and C++. I'm trying to pass a vector to a function to sort it, and return its highest value. I seem to be able to get the right answer with the code I have, but it truncates the decimal places. Here's my code:

```
double findMaxValue(vector<double> v)
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int lastIndex = v.size() - 1;
    double maxValue = v[lastIndex];

    return maxValue;
}
```

I found some similar questions on here, but they all seem to be far above my level of knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truncation happens outside of the code of your function. This may also be related to printing of the value in the code that calls `findMaxValue`.

Here are a few notes on the implementation:

- You can pass `v` by reference to avoid copying
- You can make `vector<double>` a `const` because you do not modify it inside `findMaxValue`
- You can use `v.back()` instead of `v[lastIndex]`. If you make `v` a `const`, you will need to use `v.back()` to avoid errors.
- Unless this is a learning exercise that requires you to write your own `findMaxValue`, `*std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end())` will do the same thing on non-empty vectors.